# How to combine the values of a column in single cell after applying groupby in Python

Tags: join, lambda

[image]

after applying groupby I got this. But I want to add all labels grouped by class in one column as labels like following in Python code
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('class').agg({'labels':lambda x: list(x)})
```

this worked for me.